# 1995 jeep grand cherokee stopped working

Tags: jeep

My jeep the other night had slowed to a stop, the check gauges light came on and my steering wheel took a ton of effort to turn. My lights and my radio were still on. I asked a friend to look at it, but he didn't see anything wrong with it. This was actually the 2nd time it's happened. The other time it was summer outside, and we thought we had fixed it. Obviously not.

Comment: Are you saying the engine unexpectedly stopped?

Comment: Yes. It started right back up and I've been able to drive it

Comment: So you want to know why the engine stopped, not why the steering wheel became difficult to turn?

Comment: Well I would like to know both

Comment: The steering will have become difficult to turn when the engine stopped running because the power steering pump will have stopped running, since it is powered by the engine.

Answer (score 1):

did you look at the serpentine belt, make sure it is tight enough and check the tensioner on the belt. try and pull the serpentine belt, the belt should be stiff, and if you could pull it without effort, replace the tensioner on the belt.

I think the belt might be slipping on the accessories like power steering, alternator, compressor etc.

this should probably be in the comments section.
Sorry for writing as an answer, do not have enough reputation to comment.